# Javascript - Chrome Console - What does "Array(0)" mean?

Tags: javascript, arrays, google-chrome

I am using Console.log to identify the array values of a function. While examining the console I see a number of places where Array(0) exists:

[image]

In particular, I have created an array of key value pairs (see "x" and "testedElements" (same object) at the bottom of the picture above.)

When I expand "x" out that "Array(0)" sits at the top of an array element... I am unsure what "Array(0) means.. does it signify that this element is an array?
[image]

I was actually trying to recreate the structure of "full MENU" at the top of the console picture but I have "Array(0)" displaying in the middle of testedElements/x...

Comment: It means an array with zero length.

Comment: It is initialized as array but has an object structure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's how Chrome displays an 0-length array in value summaries in the console. Empty arrays can still contain fields due to the nature of JavaScript.

```
var obj = {};
obj.array = [];
obj.array.myField = 1;
console.log(obj);
```

This will log the following in the console:

```
> {array: Array(0)}
```

And when I expand it:

```
{array: Array(0)}
  array: Array(0)
    myField: 1
    length: 0
    __proto__: Array(0)
  __proto__: Object
```

**This shows that named fields are not items in an array.**

If you want an associative array (Array with named indexes), you should use plain JavaScript objects.

```
var obj = {};
obj.A = 10;
```

Comment: Sometimes you have to ask the most basic of questions so to hit me with -4 is kinda defeating the purpose of having a question and answer forum to learn.  This answer works. Some of us are on that steep learning curve for better or worse. Incidentally this answer helped alot. I changed the initialization from  "elementWithNav = Array()" to "elementWithNav = {} as any" and this fixed the issue for me. Thanks Wazner/Miquel.

Comment: @si2030 I didn't downvote your question, but I think the reason why people might downvote is because your question didn't ask about your actual problem. It did help you personally, but it might not help others because the question is about a symptom (Unexpected display in console) and not the problem (Array vs objects for named keys).